# how to update the time_update from the form of the object?

Tags: python, django

how to update the time_update from the form of the object (file) that is attached to the main post?

models:

```
# Main
class File(BasePost):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('Заголовок'), blank=True)
time_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) # it is necessary to update this time when adding a nested attachment 

# Attachment   
class Attachment(models.Model):
        post = models.ForeignKey('File', verbose_name=_('Файл'), related_name='attachment', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        # Created user
        created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name=_('Добавил'), on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=1)
        is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name=_('Опубликовано'))
        # Times
        time_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name=_('Дата добавления'))
        time_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name=_('Дата обновления'))
```

views

```
# Attachment 
class AttachmentFileCreateView(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Attachment
    template_name = 'modules/files/attachment_create.html'
    form_class = AttachmentForm
    success_message = "Файл для поста успешно добавлен!"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        #? how to update time_update included in the post? 
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('files:file_detail',
                            kwargs={'cat_slug': self.object.file.category.slug, 'slug': self.object.file.slug})
```

I hope there is an answer)

Comment: Can you share your `AttachmentForm` code

Comment: Since you have set `auto_now=True` then the field should be updated automatically each time the object is saved. If you want to set it's value yourself, you cannot do that as `auto_now=True` implicitly sets `editable=False`.

Comment: I know. But when adding a nested object to an object, the main object is not updated. And I need to make sure that when a nested object is added, the main object to which the nested object is attached, in my case a file, is also updated.

Comment: Working! Added this to def form_valid(self, form):
File.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['pk']).update(time_update=timezone.now())

Answer (score 1):

```py
# Importing timezone
from django.utils import timezone
```

In your `form_valid` method

```py
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
    form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['pk']
    form.instance.time_update = timezone.now() 
    print(form.cleaned_data)
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Have added `form.instance.time_update = timezone.now()` assuming the field is `time_update`.

Comment: tnx, but I probably did not explain correctly, because I use a translator.

Comment: I added what I mean.